# How to pass a language variable to layout in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I just started Zend Framework 2 and i want to make it possible to attach a language to the doctype.

Bootstrap:

```
$this->layout()->setVariable('language', 'nl');
```

Layout.phtml

```
<html lang="<?php echo $language;?>">
```

This only works from the Controller, how can i fix this for the bootstrap?

The awnser:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->language = 'en';
}

// Now in your layout:
<html lang="<?php echo $this->language ?>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. You can write a custom view helper to resolve and return the language and use it in your layout like:

   ```
   <html lang="<?php echo $this->langHelper() ?>">
   ```
2. In your Module.php's `onBootstrap()` method, you can pass any variable to the layout like this:

   ```
   public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
       $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
       $viewModel->language = 'en';
   }

   // Now in your layout:
   <html lang="<?php echo $this->language ?>">
   ```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to @foozy:

Use php's `Locale` as container for the current locale. This will directly be usable for any other i18n stuff lying around (gettext, Zend\I18n, Doctrine's translatable etc);

```
use Locale;

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    Locale::setDefault('en_GB');
}
```

Using it:

```
<html lang="<?= Locale::getPrimaryLanguage(Locale::getDefault())?>">
```

If you want to be able to override the locale from your view scripts (e.g. there is a page which is "accidentally" in another locale:

```
<?php
if (!isset($locale)) {
    $locale = Locale::getDefault();
}
?>

<html lang="<?= Locale::getPrimaryLanguage($locale)?>">
```

And if required, set (only for non-default values!) the locale in your view:

```
<? $this->layout()->locale = 'nl_NL' ?>
```